# Azure WebApp, scaling beyond 50 instances

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I know that with the Premium tier, I could have up to 50 instances to put my web app on in Azure. If I needed to go beyond this, like 75 instances, what would be the most appropriate way to do this?

Maybe two different app service plans, different web app endpoints load balanced by Traffic Manager?

Thanks!

Comment: If your app needs 75 instances it probably makes enough money to justify custom development on your own hardware for infinite scalability.

Answer (score 2):

A Hosting Plan is simply a geographical collection of web servers. With in that hosting plan you can have 'x' number of servers (depending on the SKU)

The machines in a Hosting Plan will be split across fault and update domains. So that a server rack dying, or an upgrade rollout won't take out all of the servers in the hosting plan.

However what this doesn't protect you against is geographically scaled issues. If you have a hosting plan in West Europe and the West Europe region suffers an outage. At that point you could lose your entire deployment.

This is where them being a geographical collection of servers becomes an important characteristic. If you create a number of hosting plans in a number of regions, not only will you have local redundancy against fault and update outages but you will also gain redundancy against geographical outages.

Obviously if you need 500 servers, there is nothing stopping you creating 10 premium SKU hosting plans and deploying them all to the West Europe region and creating some sort of round robin DNS load balancing solution.

But the better solution is to share them across regions. Creating a hierarchy of traffic manager profiles to share the load amongst them. With the right automation you can have some regions coming on and off line as your load increases / decreases.

Personally, unless I have specifically required premium features (Biztalk etc) my preference has always been to simply deploy more service plans. It is far more cost effective.